# How to merge two php page into one php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have `index.php` and `upload.php`. `index.php` gives option of selecting an image and once clicked on upload image button, `upload.php` is called which then creates a directory and saves the image.

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Face Recognition</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
            Select file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
            <?php $file = isset($filename) ? $filename : ''; ?>
            <input type="text" name="filename" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />

            <input type="submit" value="Upload Images" />


        </form>

    </body>



</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = 'G:/dataset/' . $_POST['filename'] . "/";
    // check if directory exists
    if(!is_dir($uploaddir)){
        mkdir($uploaddir);
    }
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])  ;

    echo $uploadfile;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile);

?>
```

When upload.php is called, the page redirects to upload.php page and shows the upload file path. I dont want to redirect to upload.php. I want to keep everything in single index.php file. So that after uploading the images, it shows the upload file path on the same index.php. How can we achieve it.?

Comment: 1. merge and test if path is set OR 2. call upload using AJAX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put both in one PHP page and set the action of your form to the page itself. it would do the trick :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Face Recognition</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
            Select file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
            <?php $file = isset($filename) ? $filename : ''; ?>
            <input type="text" name="filename" value="<?php echo $file; ?>" />

            <input type="submit" value="Upload Images" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']))
  {
    $uploaddir = 'G:/dataset/' . $_POST['filename'] . "/";

    // check if directory exists
    if(!is_dir($uploaddir)){
        mkdir($uploaddir);
    }
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])  ;

    echo $uploadfile;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the functionality of `PHP_SELF` environment variable.
You have to make the **action** attribute as `form action = <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` and then add the code of **upload.php** into the same **index.php**.

For reference : [Refer this link](http://form.guide/php-form/php-form-action-self.html)